# Error when using the command firebase init / firebase login in my terminal

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, firebase-hosting

I installed firebase tools in my project by `npm install -g firebase-tools`  and `npm install firebase` then to host my project I entered the command firebase login/firebase init in my project terminal it gave me an error:

```
C:\amazon>firebase login
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:311
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\balus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\util-deprecate\node.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry    
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:303:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:516:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\balus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\winston\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:60:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\balus\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\firebase-tools\\node_modules\\util-deprecate\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'util-deprecate'
}
```

the  package.json file of my react project

```
  "name": "amazon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

can anyone tell me what is the problem

Comment: What version of Node are you using? It sounds like potentially a conflict with ES Module support somewhere.

Comment: The error message is suggesting there is a problem with your package.json file.  Please edit the question to show its contents.

Comment: I am using the recent version of node version 14. Yes i do think there is some problem in module

Comment: I included the package.json file in the question. There Error in the terminal is code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  could you tell where it all went wrong?

Comment: try uninstalling firebase-tools, downgrade to node 12, reinstall firebase-tools, then create a new empty node project in another folder. then login anew

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing the code entry point for Firebase to recognize it as a Node Application, kindly look into your project what modules are missing. The error code you shared also dictates that.

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',